# Sudoku puzzle with exactly 3 solutions

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

While published sudoku puzzles typically have a unique solution, one can easily conceive of a sudoku puzzle with two solutions. However, is it possible to construct a sudoku puzzle with exactly 3 different solutions?

Inspired by https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6.

Comment: In [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823966/smallest-integer-k-so-that-no-sudoku-grid-has-exactly-k-solutions/1412895#1412895) it is discussed what is the minimum number _k_ for which there doesn't exist a sudoku puzzle with _k_ solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this as a model (this works for $4 \times 4$ but needs to be adapted for $9\times 9$):

$\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 &   &   \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
  & 1 &   &    \\
  & 3 &   & 1 \end{array} $

With solutions

$\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 3  & 4  \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
2/4 & 1 &  4/2 &  3  \\
 4/2 & 3 &  2/4 & 1 \end{array} $

and

$\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 4  & 3  \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
2  & 1 & 3  & 4   \\
4  & 3 &  2 & 1 \end{array} $

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible. This adaptation of Andrew Stuart's tough example has two unique rectangles interacting via a triple. Let me know if this doesn't work! [starting sudoku grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmOdX.png)